# How do I install the latest minor version of a package on npm?

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

For example:

- I have version `2.0.0` of `package-name` installed.
- The latest minor version that has the same major version is `2.1.2`
- The latest major version (which would be installed if I ran `npm install package-name@latest` is `4.3.0`

**How can I install the most recent package that does not have breaking changes?**

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `npm install package-name@"<next-major.0.0"`

For example:

**`npm install package-name@"<3.0.0"`** would install the latest right before 3.0.0 (e.g. 2.11.1)

Comment: I wish there were something like `npm install package-name@latest-non-breaking` (or yarn to do this), but 'latest right before 3.0.0' is still the best answer I've had so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Npm uses semver, so you can use a variety of thing for getting close to your goal

Looking at the offical [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you could use something like:

```
npm install package-name@">=2.1.2 <2.2.0"
```

further more there are a lot of variety of ranges so you can use this forms
[Advanced Range Syntax](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) as you can see, this is a sample an interesting extract from the semver repo at the end is the answer for you:

> Advanced range syntax desugars to primitive comparators in
>   deterministic ways.
>
> Advanced ranges may be combined in the same way as primitive
>   comparators using white space or ||. Hyphen Ranges X.Y.Z - A.B.C
>
> Specifies an inclusive set.
>
> ```
> 1.2.3 - 2.3.4 := >=1.2.3 <=2.3.4
> ```
>
> If a partial version is provided as the first version in the inclusive
>   range, then the missing pieces are replaced with zeroes.
>
> ```
> 1.2 - 2.3.4 := >=1.2.0 <=2.3.4
> ```
>
> If a partial version is provided as the second version in the
>   inclusive range, then all versions that start with the supplied parts
>   of the tuple are accepted, but nothing that would be greater than the
>   provided tuple parts.
>
> ```
> 1.2.3 - 2.3 := >=1.2.3 <2.4.0
> 1.2.3 - 2 := >=1.2.3 <3.0.0
> ```
>
> X-Ranges 1.2.x 1.X 1.2.* *
>
> Any of X, x, or * may be used to "stand in" for one of the numeric
>   values in the [major, minor, patch] tuple.
>
> ```
> * := >=0.0.0 (Any version satisfies)
> 1.x := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0 (Matching major version)
> 1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <1.3.0 (Matching major and minor versions)
> ```
>
> A partial version range is treated as an X-Range, so the special
>   character is in fact optional.
>
> ```
> "" (empty string) := * := >=0.0.0
> 1 := 1.x.x := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
> 1.2 := 1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <1.3.0
> ```
>
> Tilde Ranges ~1.2.3 ~1.2 ~1
>
> Allows patch-level changes if a minor version is specified on the
>   comparator. Allows minor-level changes if not.
>
> ```
> ~1.2.3 := >=1.2.3 <1.(2+1).0 := >=1.2.3 <1.3.0
> ~1.2 := >=1.2.0 <1.(2+1).0 := >=1.2.0 <1.3.0 (Same as 1.2.x)
> ~1 := >=1.0.0 <(1+1).0.0 := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0 (Same as 1.x)
> ~0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.(2+1).0 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0
> ~0.2 := >=0.2.0 <0.(2+1).0 := >=0.2.0 <0.3.0 (Same as 0.2.x)
> ~0 := >=0.0.0 <(0+1).0.0 := >=0.0.0 <1.0.0 (Same as 0.x)
> ~1.2.3-beta.2 := >=1.2.3-beta.2 <1.3.0 Note that prereleases in the 1.2.3 version will be allowed, if they are greater than or equal
> ```
>
> to beta.2. So, 1.2.3-beta.4 would be allowed, but 1.2.4-beta.2 would
>   not, because it is a prerelease of a different [major, minor, patch]
>   tuple.
>
> Caret Ranges ^1.2.3 ^0.2.5 ^0.0.4
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the
>   [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and
>   minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions
>   0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.
>
> Many authors treat a 0.x version as if the x were the major
>   "breaking-change" indicator.
>
> Caret ranges are ideal when an author may make breaking changes
>   between 0.2.4 and 0.3.0 releases, which is a common practice. However,
>   it presumes that there will not be breaking changes between 0.2.4 and
>   0.2.5. It allows for changes that are presumed to be additive (but non-breaking), according to commonly observed practices.
>
> ```
> ^1.2.3 := >=1.2.3 <2.0.0
> ^0.2.3 := >=0.2.3 <0.3.0
> ^0.0.3 := >=0.0.3 <0.0.4
> ^1.2.3-beta.2 := >=1.2.3-beta.2 <2.0.0 Note that prereleases in the 1.2.3 version will be allowed, if they are greater than or equal
> ```
>
> to beta.2. So, 1.2.3-beta.4 would be allowed, but 1.2.4-beta.2 would
>   not, because it is a prerelease of a different [major, minor, patch]
>   tuple.
>       ^0.0.3-beta := >=0.0.3-beta <0.0.4 Note that prereleases in the 0.0.3 version only will be allowed, if they are greater than or equal to beta. So, 0.0.3-pr.2 would be allowed.
>
> When parsing caret ranges, a missing patch value desugars to the
>   number 0, but will allow flexibility within that value, even if the
>   major and minor versions are both 0.
>
> ```
> ^1.2.x := >=1.2.0 <2.0.0
> ^0.0.x := >=0.0.0 <0.1.0
> ^0.0 := >=0.0.0 <0.1.0
> ```
>
> A missing minor and patch values will desugar to zero, but also allow
>   flexibility within those values, even if the major version is zero.
>
> ```
> ^1.x := >=1.0.0 <2.0.0
> ^0.x := >=0.0.0 <1.0.0
> ```

so summarizing your example could be

```
npm install package-name@"^2.1.x"
```

Comment: This should be the ticked answer

Answer (score 8):

you can use following two methods:-

> In the simplest terms, the tilde matches the most recent minor version
>   (the middle number). ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will
>   miss 1.3.0.
>
> The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to
>   the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match
>   any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.

http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/

Comment: "The caret will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). " conflicts with "^1.2.3 will ...hold off on 2.0.0." - will it hold off on 2.0.0, the major version, or not?

Comment: as i said if you want the version as 2.x.x which is minor one you can do like this ^2.1.2 which is known latest minor version.
it won't download the 3.x.x or 4.x.x.

Comment: I understand that, but those sentences still conflict.

Comment: Did you tried it?
and can you share the package name so that i can try this and give you proper solution.

Comment: Agree with @mikemaccana - your sentences are contradictory. And from the other answer, it's actually more complicated than that.

Answer (score 8):

**major.minor.patch** = `1.0.3`

`major version` = `1` ,
`minor version` = `0` ,
`patch version` = `3`

- `Major`, `minor` and `patch` represent the different `releases` of a `package`.
- `tilde (~)` and `caret (^)` to designate which `patch` and `minor` versions to use respectively.
- `~1.0.3` - means to `install` `version 1.0.3` or the `latest` `patch` `version` such as `1.0.6`.
- `^1.0.3` - means to `install` `version` `1.0.3` or the `latest` `minor` or `patch` `version` such as `1.4.0`.
- if  `npm` `package.json` referencing a package that hasn’t reached version `1.0` yet, using the `caret(^)` symbol will only grab the `patch` `version`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like npm can't do this out of the box, but it can be done with [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates):

1. Run `ncu` to update package.json

   ```
   npx --package npm-check-updates ncu --target minor -u
   ```
2. Update package-lock.json

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Here's a sample before/after:

```
$ npm outdated
Package                             Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin     5.36.2  5.36.2  5.57.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser            5.36.2  5.36.2  5.57.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
eslint                               8.23.1  8.23.1  8.37.0  node_modules/eslint
eslint-config-prettier                8.5.0   8.5.0   8.8.0  node_modules/eslint-config-prettier
eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys    2.1.0   2.1.0   2.3.0  node_modules/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys
husky                                 8.0.1   8.0.1   8.0.3  node_modules/husky
lint-staged                          13.0.3  13.0.3  13.2.0  node_modules/lint-staged
prettier                              2.7.1   2.7.1   2.8.7  node_modules/prettier
typescript                            4.8.3   4.8.3   5.0.2  node_modules/typescript

$ npx --package npm-check-updates ncu
...

$ npm outdated
Package                             Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin     5.36.2  5.57.0  5.57.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser            5.36.2  5.57.0  5.57.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
eslint                               8.23.1  8.37.0  8.37.0  node_modules/eslint
eslint-config-prettier                8.5.0   8.8.0   8.8.0  node_modules/eslint-config-prettier
eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys    2.1.0   2.3.0   2.3.0  node_modules/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys
husky                                 8.0.1   8.0.3   8.0.3  node_modules/husky
lint-staged                          13.0.3  13.2.0  13.2.0  node_modules/lint-staged
prettier                              2.7.1   2.8.7   2.8.7  node_modules/prettier
typescript                            4.8.3   4.9.5   5.0.2  node_modules/typescript

$ npm install
...

$ npm outdated
Package     Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
typescript    4.9.5   4.9.5   5.0.2  node_modules/typescript
...
```

Answer (score 4):

### You can use caret `^`, tilde `~` or placeholders `x`.

That's the same stuff you'll find autogenerated in your `package.json` file.

In SemVer (semantic versioning), the segments are `major.minor.patch`.

- `^` will match the latest **minor** version.
- `~` will match the latest **patch** version.
- `x` will match the latest on ***the position***, where it is used.
- `@latest` or *nothing* will match the **latest**.

Take `yarn` package as an example. There is a reason why people would choose v1 instead of v2.

All these will install `1.22.19` (which is current v1 latest).

```bash
npm i yarn@1.x
npm i yarn@1.x.x
npm i yarn@^1
# edge cases
npm i yarn@~1    # install latest patch, if minor is not specified use latest
npm i yarn@^1.2  # caret matches latest minor. Specified minor x.2 is ignored.
```

All these will install `1.15.2`.

```bash
npm i yarn@1.15.x
npm i yarn@~1.15
# edge cases
npm i yarn@~1.15.1  # tilde matches latest patch. Specified patch x.x.1 is ignored.
```

---

*note*, when installing with `yarn` on Windows

> A caret (^) character in a command line means that the character immediately following it is interpreted literally, rather than as a control character.
> [sauce](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3270#issuecomment-302699815)

It is therefore necessary to quote the package version

```bash
yarn add "yarn@^1"
```

---

The best way to learn is with a hands on trial and error with a SemVer Calculator.
https://semver.npmjs.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and, coming from a Java & Maven environment, I would first search the https://www.npmjs.com/ for each of my specific package.

Then I would look at the Versions tab of the package and find out more about its versions. **I assume that major versions bring breaking changes, while minor versions contain only code improvements and bug fixes**, at least this is the convention. But reading the manual always helps :)

Sometimes, the version predicates can be composed like this: "codelyzer@5.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."