# How to run `npm update` so it updates the version numbers to the latest compatible in package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-update

I have, for instance, `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0"` in `package.json` and would like it to be update to latest compatible minor version, which would be `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2"` at the moment.
And I would like it to be done for all dependencies.

Note that I wouldn't want to install `@latest` for all packages, only the wildcard compatible minor versions.

Is this possible to achieve?

How else do you force bouncing up the dependency versions? Am I missing something?
I am aware that 4.12.2 is installed for ^4.11.0, but I would like it to be reflected in package.json to track updates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest minor version of a package on npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533030/how-do-i-install-the-latest-minor-version-of-a-package-on-npm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-can-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be duplicate with [How to update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073603/12696893).

Strange that there is no npm built-in support for this (?)